# How to avoid search Query OF @UniqueConstraint in JPA

Tags: jpa, unique-constraint

I want to improve performance by not doing search query where i know that data will be unique.(In my app every new user will require default data. Which will be created in server side where there is no need to do unique test.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Could you share the relevant code, explain how it currently behaves and how you want it to behave, plus the attempts you tried already? See [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: When You have @UniqueConstraint on any entity and insert value in that entity first search query is fired. I Know that i can Drop constraint But that would be permanent thing. What i want is to avid query for one method without changing database. If you understand the question then there is no need for code otherwise thank you for HELP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@UniqueConstraint is only used for schema generation. JPA doesn't do any search for unique constraints at runtime.